# how to use grep to only extract a certain column from a linux command output

Tags: text-processing, grep

I want to use grep to only see a certain column from the output of a Linux command. When I use this command, I get the following output:

```
$ ps ax | grep sshd | grep  'priv' | sort -k 3
     4886 ?        Ss     0:00 sshd: vpnuser002 [priv]
      10637 ?        Ss     0:00 sshd: vpnuser003 [priv]
      10651 ?        Ss     0:00 sshd: vpnuser003 [priv]
      11594 ?        Ss     0:00 sshd: vpnuser003 [priv]
      11669 ?        Ss     0:00 sshd: vpnuser003 [priv]
      11817 ?        Ss     0:00 sshd: vpnuser003 [priv]
       9680 ?        Ss     0:00 sshd: vpnuser003 [priv]
       4034 ?        Ss     0:00 sshd: vpnuser006 [priv]
```

What must I change in my command to only see the last column? Like this:

```
    sshd: vpnuser002 [priv]
    sshd: vpnuser003 [priv]
    sshd: vpnuser003 [priv]
    sshd: vpnuser003 [priv]
    sshd: vpnuser003 [priv]
    sshd: vpnuser003 [priv]
    sshd: vpnuser003 [priv]
    sshd: vpnuser006 [priv]
```

I am using Ubuntu Linux.

Comment: Do you have to use `grep`? `cut` is better suited for the task I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could output the command column with `o command` without header `h` and then `grep` for the specific output:

```
ps axho command | grep '^sshd:.*\[priv\]$' | sort
```

Answer (score 1):

##### Like this:

```
$ <INPUT> | grep -o '\bsshd: .*\[priv\]$'
```

or

```
ps -C sshd all | grep -o '\bsshd: .*\[priv\]$'
```

##### Output

```
sshd: vpnuser002 [priv]
sshd: vpnuser003 [priv]
sshd: vpnuser003 [priv]
sshd: vpnuser003 [priv]
sshd: vpnuser003 [priv]
sshd: vpnuser003 [priv]
sshd: vpnuser003 [priv]
sshd: vpnuser006 [priv]
```

##### The regular expression matches as follows:

| Node | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `\b` | the boundary between a word char and something that is not a word char |
| `sshd:` | 'sshd: ' |
| `.*` | any character except \n (0 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `\[priv\]$` | '[priv]', at the end of line: '$' |